Looking to perform HTTP POST from XSLT using either Java or .NET calls from Saxon
I work with a proprietary tool that leverages XSLT through the Saxon 10 engine.
I'm looking to find a way to send a payload from my XSL to an API endpoint. The payload is too large for a GET (which I was able to do in XSL) so I need it to be a POST.
The EXPath http-client extension is not available to me, but Saxon does allow you to call either .NET or Java functions.
I'm not a .NET developer, but I have used a variation of this code snippet below through Windows Workflow Foundation and that one submits fine. I thought maybe I could convert it to Saxon friendly XSLT to accomplish the same thing.
var url = "https://httpbin.org/post";
var client = new HttpClient;
var content = new StringContent(payload, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

What I want to do is replicate that kind of code but inside of an XSLT stylesheet using Saxon's ability to work with .NET.
Using the Saxonica documentation as a reference, along with other XSLT examples we have internally, I started writing this:
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:net="clitype=System.Net.Http.HttpClient"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="postTest">
    
    <xsl:variable name="req" select="net:new()"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

I didn't get much further as even this reports an error from the Saxon engine.
I also tried ChatGPT to see if it would give me some ideas. It gave me similar examples and they too all generate "Cannot find a X-argument function in ...". This was the code it gave me:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:net="clitype:System.Net.Http"
                xmlns:encoding="clitype:System.Text.Encoding"
                exclude-result-prefixes="net encoding">
  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="url" select="'https://httpbin.org/post'" />
        <xsl:variable name="client" select="net:HttpClient()" />
        
        <!-- Prepare the payload -->
        <xsl:variable name="payload" select="'nothing'" />
        <xsl:variable name="content" select="net:StringContent($payload, encoding:UTF8(), 'application/json')" />
        
        <!-- Send the POST request -->
        <xsl:variable name="response" select="net:HttpClient.PostAsync($url, $content)" />
        
        <!-- Read the response -->
        <xsl:variable name="responseBody" select="net:HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync($response)" />

        <!-- Output the response body -->
        <xsl:message>Response:</xsl:message>
        <xsl:value-of select="$responseBody"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Does anyone here have any experience doing something like this within XSLT or .NET? I don't even care if it's .NET as Java is also supported in Saxon.
I really need to be able to POST a portion of my XML data to an external API, but I cannot add any additional libraries to my XSLT processor or Saxon.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Is that Saxon PE or EE? Because HE certainly doesn't call arbitrary .NET code by reflection, it provides a feature called integrated extension functions but that would require you to write and compile additional .NET (e.g. C#) code.

This seems like a bad design decision, why would your view be making http calls? Seems like something that should be done by the controller if using MVC

Does your "proprietary tool" give you any control over the C# or Java code used to invoke the transformation?

I'm pretty sure the product is using Saxon EE. We have used the clitype: options in the namespace declaration to call other .NET methods, including ones from custom DLLs we have built ourselves.
The tool being used is nothing more than a glorified Notepad++ which merges a series of XSLT sheets together, and passes them through Saxon with the XML to produce a result. It's used mainly as a tool to write WordML / Office Open XML documents using XSLT as the data transformation engine. The rendered XML is then passed to Aspose Words to form a real document.

I'm looking to do the POST from XSLT so I can pass the original XML data to a Power Automate flow to do additional processing the cloud version of the document assembly engine (powered by XSLT) cannot do. The host engine has no mechanism to pass the XML data to Power Automate. It can only pass the final rendered document. So I'm trying other ways to get the XML from the stylesheet to Power Automate, which is where the .NET usage in XSLT comes in. And I have no ability to insert custom .NET or Java code when this runs in the cloud. I'm limited to only what the Saxon XSL engine lets me do.

For the onprem version of this custom tool, I'd get my .NET guy to just code a custom DLL and we'd call it directly like we do for many other applications. But in the cloud, we can't add any proprietary code because the 3rd party vendor has it locked down. I can't blame them for the lockdown as they can't control what code might be in our DLL, but it also makes it harder for me to get that XML to Power Automate.

I fumbled some reflexive Java calls together that at least run through both Saxon EE 10.9 Java as well as .NET that do a POST request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:BufferedReader="java:java.io.BufferedReader"
    xmlns:InputStreamReader="java:java.io.InputStreamReader"
    xmlns:OutputStream="java:java.io.OutputStream"
    xmlns:HttpURLConnection="java:java.net.HttpURLConnection"
    xmlns:URL="java:java.net.URL"
    xmlns:JString="java:java.lang.String"
    xmlns:Stream="java:java.util.stream.Stream"
    xmlns:Charset="java:java.nio.charset.Charset"
    xmlns:ByteBuffer="java:java.nio.ByteBuffer"
    xmlns:StandardCharsets="java:java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets"
    xmlns:jt="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="payload" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">{ "Name" : "John Doe", "Age" : 42 }</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:param name="url" as="xs:string">https://httpbin.org/post</xsl:param>
   
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" expand-text="yes">
        <xsl:variable name="uri" as="xs:anyURI" select="xs:anyURI($url)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="java-url" as="jt:java.net.URL" select="URL:new($uri)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="conn" select="URL:openConnection($java-url)"/>
        <xsl:message select="HttpURLConnection:setRequestMethod($conn, 'POST')"/>
        <xsl:message select="HttpURLConnection:setRequestProperty($conn, 'Content-Type', 'application/json; utf-8')"/>
        <xsl:message select="HttpURLConnection:setRequestProperty($conn, 'Accept', 'application/json')"/>
        <xsl:message select="HttpURLConnection:setDoOutput($conn, true())"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="os" select="HttpURLConnection:getOutputStream($conn)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="utf8Charset" select="Charset:forName('utf-8')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="payloadJavaString" as="jt:java.lang.String" select="JString:new($payload)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="byteArray" select="ByteBuffer:array(Charset:encode($utf8Charset, $payloadJavaString))"/>
        <xsl:message select="OutputStream:write($os, $byteArray, 0, count($byteArray))"/>
        <xsl:message select="OutputStream:close($os)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="responseCode" select="HttpURLConnection:getResponseCode($conn)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="br" select="BufferedReader:new(InputStreamReader:new(HttpURLConnection:getInputStream($conn), 'utf-8'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="response" select="BufferedReader:lines($br) => Stream:toArray()"/>
        <result code="{$responseCode}">{$response}</result>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


I punched this into Oxygen XML 23.1 and it worked like a freaking charm. Awesome. However, it seems that my proprietary tool does not like the code. It spits back two weird errors: Error Attribute end value delimiter expected. Line 37, position 73. and Error javax.activation.DataHandler java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler.
I suspect these are directly related to how Saxon is implemented with this tool.
Thanks a million for this as it may be helpful in other projects.

So I did a little more digging and found that it was "response" variable line that the tool doesn't like. When I replaced the => with =>, those errors all disappeared. But it did produce a rather useless error that reads:
java.lang.NullPointerException
I'm not a Java guy so I have no idea what this really means. Plus, it's confusing given that  Oxygen processes it fine, but my stupid custom tool does not.

@Zor, you could try <xsl:variable name="response" select="Stream:toArray(BufferedReader:lines($br))"/> instead of <xsl:variable name="response" select="BufferedReader:lines($br) => Stream:toArray()"/>.

Thanks for the suggestion, but no go there either. It produced the exact same error.
But just for argument's sake, the "payload" could contain anything right? So I could in theory user this variable to store the entire XML I am processing?

You can certainly POST XML that same way although I would expect you to use a content type of application/xml and of JSON. But in the end it all depends on the format your API expects.

Within Oxygen at least I was able to base64 encode my XML and just pass it as a string. On the Power Automate side I just then decode it and read the xpaths. Works like a charm.
Now if I could only figure out why the proprietary tool is kicking back that stupid error, I'd be all set.

I am afraid I am not sure what the error is about and I don't know how to find some clue about that other than suggesting that your try the support of that proprietary tool.

Any chance you happen to know how to write the same code you did above, except use C# methods instead of Java?

@Zor, I am not sure how easy/well the clitype approach works with Saxon .NET EE, perhaps raise that as a separate question or directly on the Saxonica support site, I would hope that Michael Kay and/or O'Neil from Saxonica have better knowledge on that as they designed and implemented that stuff, as far as I know. My attempt similar to what you tried in your first XSLT sample unfortunately failed on the new without giving me a clear idea how to change/improve the code. And usually I just write integrated extension functions as the cleaner/safer approach, but that is no option in your env

Thanks for the redirect on the Saxonica support. I have posted this info over there in hopes someone there might have an idea for me. Thanks again.
